# i m trying to change div background color but do not. create new function for change element background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<body>
    
        <input type="color" id="inputColor">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number" id="inputDivNumber">
        <button onclick="createDiv()">Create Div</button>
        <button onclick="changeBackground()">Change Div Background</button>
        <div id="output" class="divOutput"></div>
    <script>
        var div;
        function createDiv() {
            var i = 0;
            var divValue = document.getElementById("inputDivNumber").value;
            while (i < divValue) {
                div = document.createElement("div");
                //div.innerHtml=i;
                i++;

                div.setAttribute('class', 'divclass');
                document.getElementById("output").appendChild(div);

            }
        }
        function changeBackground() {

            
            

            document.getElementsByClassName('.divclass').style.backgroundColor);

        }
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a function to change the background color u can proceed the following :

```js
function changeBackgroundColor(element, color) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Please next time search by your own before posting and explain what is the problem

Here's your code fixed :
https://codepen.io/LENNY74/pen/ZEKzpNo